# iOS - afnetworking 3 delete with body

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

I have a rest service which works with DELETE method and http body. But I don't get it to work.

This is what I've tried.

```
super.manager.requestSerializer.HTTPMethodsEncodingParametersInURI = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"GET", @"HEAD", nil];
```

Another attempt:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"DELETE"
                                                                             URLString:kApiServiceUserMailBox
                                                                            parameters:nil
                                                                                 error:nil];

    NSDictionary *params =  @{
                              @"email" : email
                              };
    NSData *myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:params];

    [req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [req setHTTPBody:myData];


    [[super.manager dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Reply JSON: %@", responseObject);
            NSDictionary* json = [super parseResponse:responseObject];
            NSLog(@"Success: %@", json);
            success();

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@, %@", error, response, responseObject);
            failure();
        }
    }] resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

`AFNetworking` does not support the combination of `DELETE` with an HTTP body.  This is because the HTTP spec does not require such support.

See [Is an entity body allowed for an HTTP DELETE request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request)

Comment: You have the source.  Change it.